# Android GPS plotter draws line from current location until stop moving

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-gps

Im making an android application that Plots from your current location and when i start move it draws a line where i moved from , and setting an interval of 30secs each with a marker every interval .. btw im using Android Studio 2.1.2 thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question - it is not obvious what you are asking about exactly.  Also, consider posting the code you have so far...

Comment: i want to make an application that plots(with marker) from my current location and draws a line when i start moving. i want to set a marker for every interval it gives a location request. i Dont have a code yet

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is too broad, I think you can use the [`Polyline`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) for it. The `Polyline` class defines a set of connected line segments on the map. A `Polyline` object consists of a set of LatLng locations, and creates a series of line segments that connect those locations in an ordered sequence.

To know how to create it and different information about `Polyline`, just check the documentation link above.

I also found this [tutorial](http://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part3) that I think can help you in what you want to achieve.
Just check the video inside it to know how this tutorial works. If this is the one that you like, then there is a code here that you can follow.

Here is the [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPWYorS68WE) that you can find inside that tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your idead sir Kendi , are you a filipino ? maybe i can explain it clearly